# How to force a server to return my IP address in IPv4 and not IPv6?

Tags: php, ip, ipv6, ipv4

**Scenario**

I have a tiny PHP script on a server that echoes the IP address of any client reaching it so the address can be added to the cpanel MySQL remote hosts table via the API. I call this script using IdHTTP1.Get() passing the url of the script. I'm testing this by using the Bitdefender VPN to give me a new IP address each time before I run the delphi code to get my current IP address.  The code for the PHP script and the delphi calling code are below.

**Problem**

If I open the VPN to give myself a new IP address and then run the code it returns an IPv6 address.
If I then run the code again, without disconnecting the VPN ie I still have the same address, then on the second call I get a IPv4 address.
Each subsequent time I run the code I get the same IPv4 address, as I would expect.

If I close the VPN and open it again to get a different IP address, the same thing happens. ie the first time I run the code I get an IPv6 address and the subsequent times I get a IPv4 address

e.g. First time:  2a02:2498:e000:2001:8418:7195:9f43:a0f   Second and subsequent times:  88.202.181.53

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/1199129/how-web-browser-determines-when-to-use-ipv4-or-ipv6-to-connect-to-the-destinatio/1199141#1199141) explains that either address format might get returned but the pattern I'm getting seems quite consistent.

**Question**

Is there a way to force the code to always return an IPv4 address?  (Without my code repeatedly asking for the address until it gets one in IPv4)

**Additional info**

[This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/698471/force-use-of-ipv6-address-over-ipv4-address) seems to allude to a solution but I don't really understand the accepted answer enough to apply it to my case.

This page, https://www.ipify.org/ under API usage, shows how to get my IPv4 or IPv6 address using https://api.ipify.org or https://api64.ipify.org so it should be possible to say which I want in my script

**myip.php code**

```
<?php
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $ip;
?>
```

**The Delphi function that calls the PHP script (IdHTTP1 is an Indy TIdHTTP component on the form)**

```
function TFrmMain.getmyipaddress: string;
var url : string;
begin
  url :=  'https://Thedomain.com/myip.php';
  Result := '';
  try
     try
     theip :=  IdHTTP1.Get(url);    
     Result := Trim(theip);
     if result = '' then   showmessage( 'Failed to get a sensible IP address from myip.php on server:');
    finally
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Failed to get IP address from myip.php on server:' +slinebreak +
      e.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ipify.org can only tell you both your IPv4 and your IPv6 address because it has different domains for IPv6 and IPv4. The website at https://www.ipify.org/ will make requests to different domains using javascript.

An http request can be made using either IPv4 or IPv6 and naturally, the webserver will know your connecting IP address from the TCP headers -- after all, that is where it sends its response. It is up to the client to decide whether to make the http request via IPv4 or IPv6 but if the domain has only either an A (IPv4) or an AAAA (IPv6) record, the client has really no choice.

The domain name api6.ipify.org is only resolved to IPv6 addresses, api4.ipify.org only to IPv4, therefore a client can never connect to api4.ipify.org via IPv6 and vice versa.

If you want your php script to always return the IPv4 address of the client, make sure it cannot be connected to via IPv6 by hosting it on a domain that can only be resolved to an IPv4 Address.

Comment: Ah yes, that would be a solution, thank you. Unfortunately I am stuck with the domains I have and am getting the IP address from the domain hosting the database (and many PHP automation scripts). It probably wouldn't make financial sense to port everything to a different domain just so that I could get one that only resolved to IPv4 - if any exist.

Comment: I suppose I don't really understand which agents are ar play here. Is it the server that decides whether to tell me my IP address in IPv4 or IPv6 format or is it something in the way I ask the question that tells the server whether I'm accessing asking it to resolve my request as IPv4 or IPv6?

Comment: I have added a clarification to my answer. The decision is made by the clients browser, typically it chooses IPv6 when available.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'm not using a browser, just a Indy HTTP component in Delphi, but that component has its protocol option set to IPv4, which is why I was surprised the server responded with IPv6. I guess it's the PHP script on the server that is asking using IPv6. Looks like I can do nothing about it unless I change how I'm getting my IP address altogether. Yours is marginally the clearer answer and got there first so I'll accept that.

Comment: Ok it applies to any client but if you control the client then you should also control the IP version it uses for connecting. I cannot tell you how to select the IP version in delphi when making an http request -- maybe open a new question if you get stuck with this

Comment: @ Gamification Thanks I did that on Stack overflow [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77828145/why-do-queries-run-through-mydac-tmyconnection-sometimes-fail-because-the-connec) but as usual, my question got shot down in flames by the unhelpful, know it all trolls on SO who appear less interested in helping than exhibiting their superiorly.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` contains the remote address of the socket that is open for making the request. It can be either IPv4 or IPv6 address, depending on what the client has chosen to use.

There are several criteria for the client to select either IPv4 or IPv6 when connecting to domain:

- If client doesn't have a suitable IPv6 address, it uses IPv4 for communication
- If the domain does not have an AAAA record record in DNS, the client will use A record, that is IPv4
- If the client determines there are issues with IPv6, it will fall back to IPv4

So, if you want to ensure that `REMOTE_ADDR` always has IPv4 address, you need to use a domain name that only has A record.

If you have control over the client's networking, then you can disable IPv6 in the client.